# CRM 2011 Duplicate detection - disable ability for users to deactivate

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have quite a lot of duplicates in our CRM 2011 system. We are looking at implementing a few duplicate detection rules that we be triggered when a user attempts to save their account or contact.

However, we do not allow standard users to deactivate accounts or contacts but the duplicate detected frame that pops up when a user attempts to save a duplicate allows them to do so (via More Actions).

I have checked permissions but they only have read access for the duplicate detection rule (which they need in order to view the potential duplicates).

Does anybody have any ideas about how I can remove the deactivate option?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you just wanting to alert the user that there may be a duplicate but not allow them to deactivate the existing one?

Comment: Hi Daryl, that is correct, We just want a notification so that the user can make their own decision on whether to create the new record or whether they should use the existing record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the UI for how the Dup Rules work.  If you truly want that functionality, You could make a rest call to perform the save, inside of the onSave handler, then check for the Dup Detection error response, and present your own error dialog that allows the user to create anyways.

Comment: Thank you very much...this is just as I suspected.